# Matlab trapz but splitting areas above and below the x-axis

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm trying to find the area under a curve in the region both above the x-axis (from y = 0 to +inf) and below the x-axis, (y = 0 to -inf), separately.

As far as I can figure out, I can use

```
int = trapz(x,y)
```

to get the area under the curve, but not as 2 separate values.

For example, if we have x = [0,1,1,2] & y = [7,7,-4,-4]

Trapz will work out "3" as the area ((7.*1) + (-4.*1)), but I want the values of the area above the x-axis and below the x-axis as 2 separate numbers, 7 & -4.

Trapz must fit the trapezoids, calculate the area of the trapezoids and then sum over all. I want a way to fit & find the areas of the trapezoids, but then sort them in to +ve & -ve and finds the sum's of the +ve and -ve areas.

The documentation for trapz: https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html

Comment: Not sure you can integrate over unlimited intervals using ```trapz```. If you can express the curve as a function, you could use ```integral``` instead, and you'd be able to split the integration range as you prefer.

Comment: Thanky you picchiolu. I can just use trapz for my data, but alas I need more than what I can get with trapz (at the moment). I've had sometime to think and reworded the question hopefully get to the answer I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to be careful about how you handle the segments where a zero-crossing happens. [Picchiolu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74793007/3978545) is much simpler to implement, but ignores this case and you will introduce errors with that approach.

The clearest way is probably to just write your own implementation of the trapezium rule and handle each segment accordingly, with particular focus on handling segments which cross `y=0`.

See the comments for details

```
% Demo data
x = [1 2 3 6 7 9 12 13 14 16];
y = sin(3*pi*(x/max(x)));

% Trapz with sign change
aPos = 0; % positive area
aNeg = 0; % negative area
% Loop over point pairs
for ii = 2:numel(x)
    idx = (ii-1:ii);    % two points we care about
    dx = diff(x(idx));  % change in x
    my = sum(y(idx))/2; % mean y
    sgn = sign(y(idx));
    if prod(sgn) >= 0 % Both y values are same sign or one/both equals 0
        % two y points have same sign, simple trapezium area added to +/-
        if max(sgn) > 0 % at least one y is positive
            aPos = aPos + (dx * my);
        else % 0 or -1 sign
            aNeg = aNeg + (dx * my);
        end
    else % change in sign
        pct = 1 - y(ii) / diff(y(idx)); % percentage into interval  
        if sgn(1) < 0
            pct = 1 - pct;      
        end
        aPos = aPos + sum( y(idx)/2 .* pct .* dx .* (y(idx)>0) );
        aNeg = aNeg + sum( y(idx)/2 .* (1-pct) .* dx .* (y(idx)<0) );
    end
end

% Total area
aTotal = aPos + aNeg;
```

Plot to visualise the integral. Note that the data points do not include the zero-crossing points, but the integral creates distinct segments in the above loop

[image: plot]

**As a sense check, using the above gives the same output for `aTotal` as `trapz(x,y)`.**

Comment: Nice! Thanks for taking the time to post this. My version is probably overly simplistic. I took the liberty to insert a reference to your answer in mine.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Wolfie's answer handles much better the zero-crossings and it's the way to go.

Here's a possible solution (amended based on Pranav Hosangadi's remark about multiple x-axis crossings):

```
x = [0,1,1,2]; y = [7,7,-4,-4]

y_pos = y; y_pos(y<0) = 0; % focus on area above x-axis
res1 = trapz(x, y_pos);
y_neg = y; y_neg(y>0) = 0; % focus on area below x-axis
res2 = trapz(x, y_neg);
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm working it experimentally collected data and so I can't use a function. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This doesn't really work for a function that crosses the X axis multiple times

Comment: @PranavHosangadi can you explain a little more about the x crossings?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @user2587726 if the curve crosses the x-axis multiple times, you'd need a more sophisticated approach to splitting the data into subdomains on which ```trapz``` can be  applied.

Comment: Note this approach introduces some error. In a trivial case you might have `x=[1,2];` and `y=[+5,-5];`, setting `y=[+5,0]` would give you an integral of `2.5`, whereas the actual integral of the segment above `y=0` should be `1.25`. Over a larger curve this error is likely small, but worth being aware that adding your positive and negative areas from this approach would be different to the net total from a single integral.